# How to implement joins with the help of custom map & custom reduce scripts in Hive

Tags: hive

I am newbie to hive and I am trying to implement a task in Hive.
I come to know that we can create map scripts and reduce scripts in hive, but I am confused about that what to include in map-scripts and reduce scripts?

Can anyone tell me what to include in map & reduce scripts so that I can try for implementing the join condition using it?
Is there any material so that I can idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive generates map/reduce tasks in the back end. To query the data in hive you go into the Hive CLI ($HIVE_HOME/bin/hive) and execute Hive-SQL (HQL) commands. You can do joins in HQL.

The best reference I use when developing queries to run against my data stored in hive is http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/LanguageManual.